# Setting a select element based on data in WTForms

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I need to set a select element based on data from a database on page load.

For instance, if my database looks like this:

```
+----+--------+
| id | status |
+----+--------+
| 0  | foo    |
| 1  | bar    |
| 2  | baz    |
+----+--------+
```

I would like to load a page that has three rows that each have a select named status dynamically loaded with foo, bar, and baz, respectively.

How do I set several selects in a page dynamically with the data in a database?

I have looked through the documentation and I couldn't find anything built in to do this. I also have a pretty heavily modified field render macro in a jinja template that I can mess with.

Edit: Some code is posted below:

The form class:

```
class ItemForm(Form):
  status = SelectField(
  "Status",
    choices=[
      ("foo", "foo"),
      ("bar", "bar"),
      ("baz", "baz")
    ]
  )
```

The view to display the actual data from the database (`display.html`):

```
{% for item in items %}
  <div class="id">{{ item.id) }}</div>
  <div class="status">{{ form_field(itemForm.status, value=item.status) }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The macro to display a form field:

```
{% macro form_field(field) -%}
  {% set with_label = kwargs.pop('with_label', False) %}
  {% set no_label = kwargs.pop('no_label', False) %}
  {% set placeholder = '' %}

  {% if not with_label %}
    {% set placeholder = field.label.text %}
  {% endif %}

  <div class="form-group {% if field.errors %}error{% endif %}">
    {% if with_label %}
      <label for="{{ field.id }}" class="control-label">
        {{ field.label.text }}{% if field.flags.required %} *{% endif %}:
      </label>
    {% endif %}

    {% set class_ = kwargs.pop('class_', '') %}

    {% if field.flags.required %}
      {% set class_ = class_ + ' required' %}
    {% endif %}

    {% set prefix = kwargs.pop('prefix', '') %}
    {% set postfix = kwargs.pop('postfix', '') %}

    {% if prefix or postfix %}
      <div class="input-group">
    {% endif %}

    {% if prefix %}
      <div class="input-group-addon">{{ prefix }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if field.type == 'BooleanField' %}
      <label class="checkbox">
        {{ field(class_=class_, **kwargs) }}

        {% if with_label %}
          {{ field.label.text|safe }}
        {% endif %}
      </label>
    {% else %}
      {% set class_ = class_ + ' form-control' %}

      {% if field.type in ('TextField', 'TextAreaField', 'PasswordField') %}
        {% set class_ = class_ + ' input-xlarge' %}
      {% elif field.type == 'FileField' %}
        {% set class_ = class_ + ' input-file' %}
      {% endif %}

      {% if field.type == "SelectField" %}
        {{ field(class_=class_, placeholder=placeholder, default=2, **kwargs) }}
      {% else %}
        {{ field(class_=class_, placeholder=placeholder, **kwargs) }}
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if postfix %}
      <div class="input-group-addon">{{ postfix }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if prefix or postfix %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if field.errors %}
      <span class="error help-inline">{{ field.errors|join(', ') }}</span>
    {% endif %}

    {% if field.description %}
      <p class="help-block">{{ field.description|safe }}</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{%- endmacro %}
```

Edit 2: Controller code posted below.

Controller:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  itemForm = ItemForm(request.form)

  itemsQuery = Item.query.order_by().all()

  return render_template(
    "display.html",
    items=itemsQuery,
    itemForm=itemForm
  )
```

Comment: You want each select to have only one item? or you want each select to have a three items but have a different item active for each select?

Comment: The second option. I want each select to be set differently on page load, but have the same three options when clicked.